# Fast way to move text from project to resource files (*.resx) in ASP.net

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, resourcebundle

I am working on localizing a ASP.net project. I have joined half way and now I need to move all the text from the *.aspx and *.aspc files to resource files.

The project is really big and there are about 488 files in views. What would be the best way to get them into the resource files and fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can try CodeRush plugin, there is a free version.
I have ever used it before, it is convenient. However, I cannot find a way to batch do the job.
There are other tools available too, see below.

[Code Rush plugin](http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/resources.xml)

[Resource Refactoring tool](http://resourcerefactoring.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks Wint! Will try both tools and tell you how it works :-)

Comment: Resource refactoring tools seems to be the best, but works only in VS2008 and VS2005 not VS2010 :(